# How to change date/time value from another window in delphi?

Tags: delphi-xe2

I have a handle `(H: HWND)` of `datetimepicker` box, which locates on another window/application. I want to change date time (`dt: TDateTime`) value of it with `H` and `dt`. 
Could I have any help? Thanks

Comment: Is it important to use SendMessage? Or do you actually not care how you change the state of the conyrol.

Comment: I need to change value only. Changing with SendMessage is a promotion. Please tell me your way.

Comment: You need to edit the question.

Comment: Use UIAutomation for tasks like this

Comment: Can you give more detail, or example? UIAutomation is an external library, isn't it? I didn't find it.

Comment: You can't have looked. Do a web search. We aren't here to do basic leg work for you. If you can't use web search, you are in the wrong job.

Answer (score -3):

Do it by myself is better than

```
procedure ChangeOutsideDateTime(h: HWND; dt: TDateTime);
var
  st: TSystemTime;
begin
  st.wYear:= YearOf(dt);
  st.wMonth:= MonthOf(dt);
  st.wDay:= DayOf(dt);
  st.wHour:= HourOf(dt);
  st.wMinute:= MinuteOf(dt);
  st.wSecond:= SecondOf(dt);
  st.wMilliseconds:= MilliSecondOf(dt);
  SendMessage(h, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, integer(@st));
end;
```

Comment: FYI, the RTL has a [`DateTimeToSystemTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.DateTimeToSystemTime) function in the `SysUtils` unit: `DateTimeToSystemTime(dt, st);`

Comment: `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME` carries a memory pointer, which must be marshaled when sent over process boundaries. The OS automatically marshals only certain system messages, and `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME` is not one of them. The pointer you send must point to memory that exists in the same process that owns the DTP control. So you need to use `VirtualAllocEx()` and `WriteProcessMemory()` to allocate and fill a `SYSTEMTIME` in the target process (use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and `OpenProcess()` to get the required process handle), then send that pointer in the message, then `VirtualFreeEx()` the memory.